# Azure Function based on Docker container not updating when selecting new label

Tags: docker, azure-functions

I have hosted an Azure function that is based on a docker container image. Now I have uploaded a new version of my container and selected the new label in the "Container Settings" page and saved these changes.

The problem is the azure function doesn't update and keeps on using the previously selected label of my container. Even Restart / StopStart doesn't force a refresh of the container instance.

Any idea why this is happening or do I need to throw away my azure function and deploy a completely new one?

Comment: When I was looking at the template I could see that the linux Fx is pointing to the wrong label: "linuxFxVersion": "DOCKER|**hub.azurecr.io/***:20191119065351",
"windowsFxVersion": "DOCKER|**.azurecr.io/**:20191128033235", Any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Azure Function is tied to a Docker image (with the tag), so if you created a new tag, you will have to manually update your function app configuration to point to the new tag.

If you have Azure CLI (or go to shell.azure.com), you can update the image your function app is pointing through 
-- `az functionapp config container set -n <name> -g <resource-group> --docker-custom-image-name <image-name>`, more info (and if your image is in a private registry) -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-config-container-set.

One way to avoid this in future -- have a "latest" tag or similar and point to your azure function to that. Then every time you update your image, be sure to also point the "latest" tag to the new image. This way your function app will always point to the latest image.

Comment: I fixed it by updating the template and run the deployment again. When updating the label in the azure portal only the windows container config is updated and not the linux container config as I said in my comment. I filed a bug report for this

Comment: Curious thought here. If you tag your latest image with "latest" such that a docker push replaces an already-pushed image that also has the "latest" tag, would a `az functionapp restart` be sufficient for the function app to start using the new image? I believe that a docker pull by the function app will occur when the function app restarts.

Comment: i'm pretty sure most people suggest not to use the latest tag because of caching issues.

Comment: Yep, the tag is cached, if you use something like `latest` and makes it hard to debug / check what's running.